# prometheus aggregate series produced by an arithmetic operator

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to aggregate (sum) a new series that's from an arithmetic operator.

I have

```
seriesA * seriesB
```

which produces a new series that's multiplication of `seriesA` and `seriesB`

but when I do

```
sum_over_time(seriesA * seriesB[1h])
```

it returns no data, tried putting parentheses between but still no data.

Is there a way to aggregate a new series from arithmetic operator of two series?

Comment: You need [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). It would be `sum_over_time((seriesA * seriesB)[1h:])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Michael Doubez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3480808/michael-doubez)'s comment

subqueries did the trick:

```
sum_over_time((seriesA * seriesB)[1h:])
```

and on grafana the `$__range` also works, i.e.,

```
sum_over_time((seriesA * seriesB)[$__range:])
```